# How to filter observable array and return the same

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have observable array. I want to filter observable depending upon some text. I will select option button and depending upon it i need to filter observable array and bind to table. Here is my code till now. 
This is my view

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: dataOne">
    <tr   >
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td><td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-bind="text: display"></td><td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<table >
       <tr>
            <td><input name="optbtn" type="radio" value="All"/> All</td>
            <td><input name="optbtn" type="radio" value="Selected"/> Selected</td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

Here is my view model

```
 var data1 = [{
  name1: "one",
  id: 1,
display: "<temp>Is this employee</temp> required <val>in our company</val>"
}, {
name1: "two",
id: 2,
 display: "<temp>Is this bachelor</temp>required in our group"
}, {
name1: "three",
id: 3,
 display: "Test"

}];


var viewModel = {
dataOne: ko.observableArray(data1),

};


$("input[name='optbtn']").change(function (e) {
        debugger;
        var str = "<temp>";
        var stringFromArray = "";
        if ($(this).val() == "All") {
            alert("All");
        }
        else {
            ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.dataOne(), function (data) {
                debugger;
                stringFromArray = data.display();
                if (stringFromArray.indexOf(str) == 0) {
                    return data.display();
                }

            });
        }
    });


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

If i select "Selected" option button then it should only return with text  `"<temp>`in it.
So it should return only 2 records.

How can i achieve this? When i load my page it will show all records and mark "All" button as selected. When i selected "Selected" then it must filter records.

**Update**

here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/102/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you should use the [`checked` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) on your options instead of subscribing manually to the change event.

```
<input name="optbtn" type="radio" value="All" 
       data-bind="checked: selection" />All
 <input name="optbtn" type="radio" 
       data-bind="checked: selection" value="Selected" />Selected
```

And in your view model:

```
var viewModel = {
    dataOne: ko.observableArray(data1),
    selection: ko.observable("All")
};
```

Now that you have the current selection on your viewmodel you can add a `ko.computed` (see [doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)) which does the filtering (it will trigger each time your `viewModel.selection` changes):

```
viewModel.filteredData = ko.computed(function () {
    var str = "<temp>";
    if (viewModel.selection() == "All") return viewModel.dataOne();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.dataOne(), function (data) {
        stringFromArray = data.display;
        if (stringFromArray.indexOf(str) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

And use this `filteredData` in your `foreach`:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredData">
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byJ5x/1/).

Note: you need to use `ko.utils.arrayFilter` if you want to filter an array based on a criteria instead of `ko.utils.arrayFirst` which returns the first found item. And you need to return true/false from its second parameter function to signal whether an item should be included or not.

Comment: Is this filteredarray an obs array? Cant see where its declared

Comment: Please can you tell if we can use obs array as filteredData instead of doing viewmodel.filteredData?

Comment: `filteredData` is computed property which return an regular array so not an observable array. And it is declared in the line `viewModel.filteredData = ko.computed(function () {`. You cannot really do the filtering with alone with your array because you need to store somewhere the items to restore them when the user select all again, so you will anyway end up with two arrays. Why is necessary to have  it observable or to work directly with your array?

Comment: Cant we copy obs array and then play with it? I have not used this viewmodel.filtereddata before. Let me know if possible with obs array

Comment: There is nothing special in the `viewmodel.filtereddata` syntax it just adds a new property to your `viewmodel` called  `filtereddata`. You can also do it with the coping something like :http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/103/ but using a `ko.computed` is the knockout way of doing this things.

Comment: yes thats what i wanted. Many many thanks. But as per you suggestion i will go with your first fiddle.

Comment: its bit slow when there are more than 4000 records. It takes 8 seconds to change the option button if there are more records to filter. What should i do?

Comment: i have added new question for performance. Please have a look if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186635/array-filter-is-returning-data-very-slowly